# Python iterate folder of csv and convert do json

Tags: python, json, loops, csv

I am amateur at python but I have a task of converting folder of csv to json files. I have this script working with specified CSV file but I have no idea how to make the script iterate thrue folder of csv and convert all of those csv to json. The original script:

```
import csv
import json
import pandas as pd

file = '/users/krzysztofpaszta/CSVtoGD/build-a-bridge.csv'
json_file = '/users/krzysztofpaszta/CSVtoGD/build-a-bridge.json'

#Odczyt pliku CSV
def read_CSV(file, json_file):
    csv_rows = []
    with open(file) as csvfile:
        reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
        field = reader.fieldnames
        for row in reader:
            csv_rows.extend([{field[i]:row[field[i]] for i in range(len(field))}])
        convert_write_json(csv_rows, json_file)

#Zamiana CSV na JSON
def convert_write_json(data, json_file):
    with open(json_file, "w") as f:
        f.write(json.dumps(data, sort_keys=False, indent=4, separators=(',', ': '))) 
        f.write(json.dumps(data))


read_CSV(file,json_file)
```

someone will give me a hint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [os](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html) functions, particularly `os.listdir()` to iterate over files in the directory, and safely generate new names with `os.path.splitext()`:

```
import os

DIRECTORY = "/path/to/dir"

for f in os.listdir(os.fsencode(DIRECTORY)):
     fn = os.fsdecode(f)
     pre, ext = os.path.splitext(fn)
     if ext == ".csv": 
         read_CSV(fn, pre + '.json')
```

The similar approach with [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) would be:

```
from pathlib import Path

DIRECTORY = "/path/to/dir"

files = Path(DIRECTORY).glob('*.csv') # to process files only in this dir

files = Path(DIRECTORY).rglob('*.csv') # to process files in sub-directories recursively

for f in files:
    read_CSV(f, str(f.with_suffix('.json'))) # use .with_suffix() for safe name generation
```

Answer (score 1):

You can list the csv files in a folder using pathlib:

```
from pathlib import Path

csv_files = Path().glob('*.csv')
```

Then loop over the files:

```
for csv_file in csv_files:
    csv_path = str(csv_file.absolute())
    json_path = csv_path.replace('.csv', '.json')
    read_CSV(csv_path, json_path)
```